# google script file's folder

Tags: google-apps-script

What the easiest way for specific file to retrieve the path(or id) of folder that contains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is in the [Docslist documentation : getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file?hl=fr-FR#getParents) returns an array of parent folders.
Then you can use `getName()` or `getId()`

Comment: by the way, there is no getName() member in the doc for class Folder, but it works.

Comment: I have raised an issue about the missing methods at http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2178  Please star it if you think of documentation should be up to date